# Experience Optimization 8.5 - Issues with promotions content loading for multiple promotions off of same trigger-type

Tags: web8.5, experience-optimization

I am currently working on a project where we are working through Experience Optimization and trying to get some of our use cases/scenarios to work.

We have 3 promotions enabled (attempting to accomplish or condition):

- The promotions are as follows:

[image]

- As seen in the screenshot above we have 3 promotions, all enabled and we want 1 item from each one to display
- All are tied to the claim value "**Site Subscriptions**"
- Each one has a specific value we want to look for (example: Coke, Pepsi, N/A)
- We also have them set to just display 1 item from the result set.

In essence what we are expecting is that each promotion with match our current Subscriptions claim value, which is "**taf:claim:customer:siteSubscriptions": "Coke|N/A|Pepsi**". In essence all 3 promotions should be valid at this stage since the claim value currently contains all 3 promotion scenarios above.

What is currently happening is that only the first promotion on the list of promotions is hit and it only displays the 1 item from that promotion (if I increase the number of items to display then those items do get displayed for this promotion). If I swap the order of the promotions in the image above then that one will be the one hit and it's value display.

If I go and disable the other promotions one by one, then the promotion that is enabled displays, also if I adjust the the number of items displayed from 1 to 2 or event to 3 all the items for the enabled promotion displays.

What I was expecting was for each promotion to execute since the "**Site Subscriptions**" value contains all three possible values "**Coke|Pepsi|N/A**". That is not the case, what is happening is that the first promotion is hit and only displays the 1 item and the seems to either bounce or ignore the other two promotions.

I am wondering if I may be missing something or is this expected results. I am expecting 1 item on my page from each promotion in the image above.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say they all trigger correctly and 3 or more items are allowed in the region, my money would be on the Promotions currently returning the same items and duplicates being disallowed in the "featured" region.

That would explain why only the items from the highest priority active Promotion are being shown -- the others are filtered out because they are duplicates.

You can control duplicates system-wide in the configuration or override it in each individual region.

By the way, this is a case where the XPM integration can really help you see what is going on. Alternatively, you can use the Preview window within the Fredhopper Business Manager to recreate your triggers and see if the Promotions are firing correctly and what items they are returning.